# Dynamically created Bootstrap collapse in Angular 6 not working

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular6, angular-cli

In Angular 6 I iterate through a data set in order to dynamically create an accordion/collapse.  The issue is that Bootstrap is initialized at page load, however, this accordion is created after page load, after an API call.  So after the accordion is rendered, its is not interactive, as the new DOM elements were not picked by the initilization of bootstrap at page load.

If I could just get bootstrap to re-initialize from the JS entirely, that would be perfect.

Otherwise I need to find a way to re-initialize Bootstrap collapse so that it picks up all of the new DOM additions that are created.  Here is the markup.  Ive tried $('.collapse').collapse() like the docs say but that only collapses the content, it does not initialize the controls to toggle the content.

```
<div id="accordion" *ngIf="data && data.length > 0">
  <!-- Chart -->
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let chart of data; let chartIndex = index">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading{{chartIndex}}">
      <h4 class="mb-0">
        <a href="#" 
           class="acc-btn" 
           data-toggle="collapse" 
           data-target="#collapse{{chartIndex}}" 
           aria-expanded="true">
          <span class="fa fa-chevron-up"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span>
          {{chart.sectionName}}
      </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse{{chartIndex}}" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <table class="scenario">
          <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let header of chart.headers">{{header}}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let row of chart.data">
            <td *ngFor="let value of row"><app-parent-child-data-list [data]="value"></app-parent-child-data-list></td>
          </tr>                       
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix Angular and JQuery together.  They will conflict with each other since both will be manipulating the DOM and each will have issues knowing that the other made changes.

The best solution would be to use something like NG-Bootstrap which is a pure Angular implementation of most of Bootstrap JQuery code.  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

If you were only using the accordion, you could also write your own simple function to toggle the accordion hidden/shown classes, but as your app grows you may find adding NG-Bootstrap would just be easier.